# Re-arranging the content of a range of cells with VBA Split Function

Tags: vba, excel, split

- I have a range of cells from `A8 to A188`
- The content of those cells is: LastName, FirstName. I need to change the content to FirstName Lastname in the cells to the right of it.

So for instance Cell `A8` may be

> Smith, Bob

I'd like to make Cell `B8`

> Bob Smith

and do this for every cell in that range.

I know I need to use the Split function in some way but haven't been able to wrap my head around how to do the loop or store and then re-arrage the content into the other cells.

Additionally I haven't been able to find anything on here or other sites that has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this, place this in B8:
`=TRIM(RIGHT(A8,LEN(A8)-SEARCH(", ",A8)))&" "&LEFT(A8,SEARCH(",",A8)-1)`

edit: Sorry it's not VBA. Do you need it to be VBA or would the formula work?